# How to provide code coverage threshold via Jenkins to SonarQube?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

We are setting up Jenkins CI and to ensure code quality we want to add certain thresholds for code coverage on SonarQube or else make the jenkins build fail.

I have seen an option on SonarQube - Quality gateways where we can specify threshold for code coverage, unit test pass percentage, etc.

But for me the criteria is that these thresholds should be passed via sonar plugin on Jenkins. Has anybody tried this before?